# My App.js did not look the same like in the tutorial. It did not contain a class just a function. What did a wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After creating a React app with command line (create-react-app projectname)
I did not get the expected result. I was following a tutorial step by step (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ke90Tje7VS0) and my App.js did not look the same.

My result:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What I excepted:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `create-react-app` has updated their default template over time including to use functional components over class components.

Comment: Thank you! :)
But I'm an absolute beginner with react.js, so can you help me step by step to what to do?

Comment: I'm afraid not, but there are plenty of resources on the internet for you to follow. https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Thank you :) 
At least now i know what is the problem :)